# Cannot run PostgreSQL on port 5432

Tags: tcp-ip

When I try to start PostgreSQL on port 5432, it fails saying it can't connect to the tcp address. However, after changing the config to port 5433, it starts just fine.

`waiting for server to start....2018-10-24 10:23:20.330 DST [745] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address "127.0.0.1": Permission denied
2018-10-24 10:23:20.330 DST [745] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2018-10-24 10:23:20.348 DST [745] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
2018-10-24 10:23:20.363 DST [745] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
2018-10-24 10:23:20.366 DST [745] LOG:  database system is shut down
 stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.`

I ran `sudo netstat -peanut | grep ":5432 "` to check if something occupies this port. But it does not list anything.

What might be the reason?

Comment: check here for Postgresql on port 5432: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466190/cant-connect-to-postgresql-on-port-5432